# How do I connect an external WiFi device to the USB port of my Android phone?

Tags: usb

I cannot find any android drivers that will allow me to connect an external WiFi thumb drive to the USB port of my phone. Then I intend to interface to the USB through the external WiFi device using WiFi Direct.  I do not want to root my phone so does anyone know of a way to connect these devices?

Comment: You need to rebuild your kernel with the driver added for the Wi-Fi adapter you want to connect over OTG.

Comment: Thank you Irfan.  I was looking for a solution that does not require rooting.

Comment: Yeah that's what I meant that what you are looking for isn't possible.

Comment: Irfan, I thought the driver would go on the external device, not the mobile. Windows comes with USB drivers to interface to mobiles..I was hoping there was an external WiFi thumb drive that would allow addition of a similar driver but instead of Windows it would be in Python or whatever the thumb drive was capable of running.  I guess that would require that there are USB drivers available for non Windows devices.

Comment: The concept of drivers is different on Windows and Linux. Android is based on the latter. Linux kernel usually already includes a larger number of hardware drivers than a Windows system. But mobile devices have limited hardware resources, so Android uses a *minified* Linux kernel. If your kernel doesn't have the driver of your desired WiFi adapter already built-in, you need to rebuild the kernel. Or at least load the driver as a kernel module (if luckily available). In both cases root privileges are must (which are always available on desktop systems, be it Windows or Linux).